# Nginx perl module with LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, http, nginx, perl-module, lwp

I have a web server running nginx on http://192.168.x.x, and a perl module is installed using http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html

I need to do a GET request inside that module using LWP. This is what i have:

```
my $url = "http://192.168.x.x/app/test.php";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(5); # muere a los 5 segundos sin respuesta.
$ua->default_header('Cookie' => "FOO=BAR;PATH=/");
my $resp = $ua->get($url);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print STDERR "Received reply: $message\n";
} else {
    print STDERR "HTTP GET error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print STDERR "HTTP GET error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
};
```

Everytime i do that request i get error code 500 : read timeout. But if i use another server  works just fine. The problem is when i use the same server where i run the script.

Comment: Why are you calling a php script? Where is the web server error log?   Typically when a 500 happens you get some record of it in the error log.  What does the php script have to do with the perl integration?

Comment: that piece of code is part of a subroutine what i use as handler in perl_set directive. I need to call a php script in the same server to retrive some data. There's no error msg in log... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because nginx has only one worker thread. When you call your perl code inside nginx it blocks whole server. So one nginx can't process your blocking perl code and php handler at the same time. This is deadlock. You can try [Nginx::HTTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nginx%3a%3aHTTP) which shouldn't block nginx while waiting http response. So, this will work, I think.